# Get black region from image using Tensorflow and Python

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, opencv, colors

I'm trying to get the black region from an image using TensorFlow. To this point I was using OpenCV but it fails to get the hole region given that the gray scale is very complicated.

The image I'm using is a photo of a electric meter, the whole meter is white(normally) except for the part with the numbers that is black. I would want to isolate this part in order to get the numbers later on.

To de the date, I have been using the function [`findContours` from OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html), with a defined threshold .

I have seen that TensorFlow is very potent so I think this could no be a problem, but I can't find any documentation. Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "black region"? Do you mean the largest possible square patch that is all black? Do you mean a boolean mask indicating which pixels are black? Do you mean any contiguous black region regardless of shape? And what exactly did you use in OpenCV that you would like to replicate in tensorflow?

Comment: Thanks for the anwser @David Parks, I have update the question

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow is a general purpose math library that is unique in two respects:

1. It provides automatic differentiation.
2. It has efficient kernels built to run on either the CPU or GPU.

It does have a library of `image` functions, but it's nowhere near as extensive as OpenCV, and will never be. Those are mostly for data augmentation (as it pertains to ML) and data loading.

Note that you can run OpenCV code on the GPU in many cases (I'm not sure about `findContours` in particular. So sticking with OpenCV should be considered.

But within tensorflow you would have to re-write that function yourself. In looking at the code (which I provided a link to in your question) it doesn't look very hard to do. You could replicate that in symbolic tensorflow operations in relatively short order, but nothing like that exists pre-built in tensorflow. Nor is it likely to in the future.

Comment: Thanks agains @David Parks, given that tensorflow is not the best option, do you know any other tool?? Opencv fails to get a good implementation with a grey region, with a red region works perfectly